# Lag in ScrollView with a lot of ImageButton

Tags: android, scrollview, imagebutton, lag

I'm an Android beginner and I'm building a SoundBoard app for fun with a `ScrollView` and a lot (*44 for now*) `ImageButton` side by side in 2 columns.

Here is what it looks like :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myImageButton1"
            android:tag="myTag1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="onSoundButtonClick"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/myImage1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myImageButton2"
            android:tag="myTag2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:onClick="onSoundButtonClick"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/myImage2" />
    </LinearLayout>

   // More LinearLayout below for ImageButton side by side

</LinearLayout>
```

When scrolling down fast I experience lags. I tried building the app with a `RecyclerView` but it didn't fixed the problem (I may have misused it).
Each .jpg weigh between 20Ko and 30Ko for a total of 1.24Mo for 44 images.

Do you have any clue on how to fix this ?

**Thanks !**

Comment: use Picasso its a Imageloader Lib it will load images when needed ,, plus its works on Background Thread check out this link : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/picasso-android-tutorial-picasso-image-loader-library/

Comment: @ItzikSamara I tried Picasso and it works like a charm ! But i can't find a way to play sound onClick on an item... There is nothing relating to it on internet, do you have any idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be in your layout. It's on your adapter. you have some [good practices to apply by google](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) and in alternative you can apply lazy load to your resources, you can find in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541966/3640637).

This should help you to solve your problem.